# How does the tuning differ between a concert and soprano ukulele?

Tags: tuning, alternative-tunings, ukulele

I am getting a new concert ukulele and I was wondering whether the tuning is different for a concert?

is it still GCEA? or is there a better sounding tuning than soprano standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no, the tunings are not different. The soprano and concert are usually tuned the same way: GCEA. 
The baritone uke is the only size that is normally tuned differently.

As far as "better sounding" goes, that's a matter of personal preference. One option you might try is to use a low G string; tune the G as a low G instead of the normal re-entrant high G.